# How to calculate this limit $ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1-\sqrt{1+x^2}\cos{}x}{x^4} $?

Tags: limits

$ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1-\sqrt{1+x^2}\cos{}x}{x^4} $

I tried L'Hopital, but it gets complicated.

I tried also this:

$$ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1-(1+x^2)\cos^2{x}}{x^4(1+\sqrt{1+x^2}\cos{x})} $$

$$ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin^2{x}-x^2\cos^2{x}}{x^4(1+\sqrt{1+x^2}\cos{x})} $$

, but I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: Have you tried maclaurin expansions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I shall use this idea of yours:$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\sqrt{1+x^2}\cos(x)}{x^4}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-(1+x^2)\cos^2(x)}{x^4\left(1+\sqrt{1+x^2}\cos(x)\right)}.$$Note that$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(1+\sqrt{1+x^2}\cos(x)\right)=2.$$So, what remains is to compute\begin{align}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-(1+x^2)\cos^2(x)}{x^4}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2(x)-x^2\cos^2(x)}{x^4}\\&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)-x\cos(x)}{x^3}\times\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)+x\cos(x)}x\\&=\frac13\times2\\&=\frac23,\end{align}and therefore your limit is equal to $\frac13$.

Comment: I believe the cosine is not squared in the original limit.

Comment: @GReyes Indeed. It was a typo. Thank you.

Comment: I do not see any error in my computation, neither in yours... but there has to be something wrong.

Comment: @GReyes See my comment to your answer.  You need to include the $x^4$ term of the Taylor expansion of each factor.

Comment: @RobertShore Yes, I saw that. Thank you! I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Taylor expansion:
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\sqrt{1+x^2}\cos x}{x^4}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1-(1+x^2/2+\dots)(1-x^2/2+\dots)}{x^4}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{x^4/3+\dots}{x^4}=1/3
$$

Comment: You need to include the $x^4$ terms of the Taylor expansions.  Each is multiplied by the constant term of the other factor, and they don't cancel.

Comment: Note that$$\left(1+\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^4}8+\cdots\right)\left(1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{24}+\cdots\right)=1-\frac{x^4}3+\cdots$$since $\frac1{24}-\frac14-\frac18=-\frac13$.

Comment: Thank you both! Didn’t notice that I was missing those..

Answer (score 0):

**Another way**.-Let $f(x)=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1+x^2}\cos(x)}{x^4}$. Since $f(x)=f(-x)$ and is well defined for $|x|\gt0$ by prolongement by continuity we can put $f(0)=a$ where $a$ is precisely the asked limit. One has therefore
$$1-\sqrt{1+x^2}\cos(x)=ax^4$$ Now we have
$$1-(1+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+\cdots)(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\cdots)=ax^4$$  The first coefficient in LHS is for $x^4$ and its value is equal to $\dfrac14+\dfrac18-\dfrac{1}{24}=\dfrac13$ so we have
$$\frac{x^4}{3}-\frac{x^6}{12}+\cdots=ax^4$$  from which the searched limit is $=\dfrac 13$